# How does input() function actually work?

Tags: python, stdin

I know that **print** writes decoded string on stdout, something like this in Python:

```
>>> def alt_print(*arg):
...     [x.decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for x in arg]
...     sys.stdout.write(''.join(arg) + '\n') if len(arg) < 2 else sys.stdout.write(str(arg) + '\n')
```

---

But it's still hard to understand how does input function actually capture data?

Does it use different process to first print the string and then while loop on another process to listen to the stdin?

**Note:** I couldn't find answer of this on stackoverflow, my question is how does input **specifically** works!

Comment: the code you posted doesn't seem to read `stdin` at all. What's the relation with `input()` ?

Comment: +Jean-Francois Fabre Sorry i compared print function to input function if it has any common.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I think it's just a demo of `sys.stdout`.

Comment: not my downvote BTW...

Comment: From the source code: *Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.

The prompt string, if given, is printed to standard output without a
trailing newline before reading input.

If the user hits EOF (\*nix: Ctrl-D, Windows: Ctrl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
On \*nix systems, readline is used if available.*

Comment: The C implementation is in function `builtin_input_impl` in `Python/bltinmodule.c`

Comment: @cdarke Does it use different processes to print the string and listen to stdin?

Comment: @ShellRox, no, everything is done inside one process - the python process.  Why would you think otherwise?  The sequence is straightforward, write the prompt to stdout (file descriptor 0) *then* read from stdin (file descriptor 1).

Comment: @cdarke I thought it used different processes to print string and listen to stdin for some reason, and does it use while loop to wait and listen to input? and does it use stdin log file to capture the input?

Comment: It does not use a while loop, it is known as a *blocking* call.  The process will block until there is data to be read.  I have no idea what you mean by "stdin log".  Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @cdarke I am using Mac OS X, with stdin log i mean `sys.stdin.readlines()`